# Is there a script available to split audio file in PHP?

Tags: php, audio

There certainly seems to be plenty of examples of how one might split a wav file using the frequency to get the frame-rate and avoid splitting a frame in the middle. Are there any APIs available in PHP that might utilize a thrid-party program to accomplish this? If there are no recommended APIs would anyone care to recommend a command line audio splitting utility ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find this [page](http://php.net/manual/en/refs.utilspec.audio.php) of php manual with a lot a library for audio manipulation, example of usage with OpenAl [here](http://www.lephpfacile.com/manuel-php/book.openal.php). On codecanyon I find [this script](http://codecanyon.net/item/ffmpeg-ultimate/130474).

Answer (score 2):

I have written a class, called **[Audero Wav Extractor](https://github.com/AurelioDeRosa/Audero-Wav-Extractor)**, that do what you need. I hope this will help also future users. This is the link to the project: https://github.com/AurelioDeRosa/Audero-Wav-Extractor

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use anything but FFMPEG for this, due to its extensive support for container types and codecs.

http://ffmpeg.org/

You can execute it directly, or call the PHP extension version of it.

Comment: Does this library allow to split audio file on the fly? I mean using it as a PHP extention.

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa, I'm not sure what you are asking specifically... yes you can split audio whenever you would want.

Comment: Sorry...I'll try to be more descriptive. Saying I have a file audio.wav which lasts 1 minute. And I want a piece of this file, saying from second 10 to 30. There's a PHP class of the FFMPEG library that allow me to do this?

Comment: Yes.  You can either call FFMPEG's executable directly, or the PHP extension version of FFMPEG.  I also believe there is a class wrapper for calling FFMPEG directly for PHP, but I don't know where that is.